# Implement retryWhen logic

Tags: android, session, retrofit, rx-java

I have an app which requires session (cookies) to process web calls. Im using `Retrofit+RxJava`. However, session could expire (Retrofit error with 401 Unauthorized status) and i want to reauthenticate (to get fresh cookies) and retry previous call in this case. How would i do it with `RxJava`?

My example:

```
getServerApi().getDialogs(offset, getCookies())
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
     .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
     .retryWhen(observable -> {...}) // Need some logic
     .subscribe(dialogsEnvelope -> getView().setDialogs(dialogsEnvelope),
                throwable -> getView().setError(processFail(throwable)));
```

Comment: If the session expires and you need to retry, do you get some kind of server response that indicates that (e. g. a JSON with `"success" : false`) or do you just a `RetrofitError`?

Comment: @david.mihola, updated my question. I get 401 Unauthorized (getting Retorfit error).

Comment: I think I have an idea, but I'd like to try it before posting...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use OkHttp's extremely powerful [`Interceptor`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/Interceptor.java).

```
public class RecoverInterceptor implements Interceptor {
  String getAuth() {
    // check if we have auth, if not, authorize
    return "Bearer ...";
  }

  void clearAuth() {
    // clear everything
  }

  @Override public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    final Request request = chain.request();
    if (request.urlString().startsWith("MY ENDPOINT")) {
      final Request signed = request.newBuilder()
          .header("Authorization", getAuth())
          .build();
      final Response response = chain.proceed(signed);
      if (response.code() == 401) {
        clearAuth();
        return intercept(chain);
      } else {
        return response;
      }
    } else {
      return chain.proceed(request);
    }
  }
}
```

Remember to synchronize your auth process code, so that two concurrent requests do not invoke it at the same time.

Answer (score 8):

While an `Interceptor` may be a better solution for this particular problem, the question specifically asked for a solution using `retryWhen`, so here is is one way to do it:

```
retryWhen(new Func1<Observable<Throwable>, Observable<?>>(){

    @Override
    public void Observable<?> call(Observable<Throwable>> attempts) {
        return attempts.flatMap(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<?>>() {

            @Override
            public Observable<?> call(Throwable throwable) {
                 if (throwable instanceof RetrofitError) {
                     RetrofitError retrofitError = (RetrofitError) throwable;
                     if (retrofitError.getKind() == RetrofitError.Kind.HTTP && retrofitError.getResponse().getStatus() == 401) {
                         // this is the error we care about - to trigger a retry we need to emit anything other than onError or onCompleted
                         return Observable.just(new Object());
                     } else {
                         // some other kind of error: just pass it along and don't retry
                         return Observable.error(throwable);
                     }
                 } else {
                     // some other kind of error: just pass it along and don't retry
                     return Observable.error(throwable);
                 }
             }
        });
    }
})
```

However, your `getCookies` would not be called again in the case of a simple `retry`. That would just resubscribe to the same `Observable` but `getCookies` was called before the creation of that `Observable`. So I think you would have to wrap the creation of the source `Observable` in a `defer`.

Comment: In this example `retry` would be OK too... Saves you a flatMap.

Answer (score 0):

While browsing the Internet for discovering a proper answer - i've found **[this cool gist](https://gist.github.com/alex-shpak/da1e65f52dc916716930)** describing how to refresh OAuth token with the help of `OkHttp Interceptor` (similar to accepted answer, but more complete).

It has nothing to do with RxJava, but for me it's more acceptable because i don't have to wrap each Observable with `retryWith` logic - everything is done on lower level (`OkHttp` library).