# Retry http request with changed baseUrl in Retrofit on Particular error from Server

Tags: android, retrofit2

In app we use Retrofit2 with Rx to communicate with our server. I want to **change baseUrl** in Retrofit when I get particular http error code. I found [example to change Request header on error with Interceptor.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30536114/2098878)
Preferably I want to have that logic in Retrofit, since its  single place where our multiple request pass.
Other solution to use Rx `retryWhen()` is difficult to use, since we have many requests in different places in our project app.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using RxJava the easiest way is to chain the request with operator `onErrorResumeNext`

for instance you have `whiteApi` with base Url XXXX and black retrofit `blackApi` with different baseUrl (called when `whiteApi` fails):

```
whiteApi.getCat().onErrorResumeNext( err-> blackApi.getCat() ) ...
```

if `blackApi` fails you can also chain request with `.onErrorReturn()` and mock the response.

Answer (score 0):

Simply on failing 1st case create another retrofit instance with new base url and after doing your job clear it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a class wrapper for your service :

```
public class ServiceGenerator {  
    public static String apiBaseUrl = "http://base.url/api";
    private static Retrofit retrofit;

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addConverterFactory(relevantConverter)
                    .baseUrl(apiBaseUrl);

    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient =
            new OkHttpClient.Builder();


    private ServiceGenerator() {
    }

    public static void changeApiBaseUrl(String newApiBaseUrl) {
        apiBaseUrl = newApiBaseUrl;

        builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .addConverterFactory(relevantConverter)
                        .baseUrl(apiBaseUrl);
    }

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, String baseUrl) {
        builder.client(httpClient);

    return builder.build().create(serviceClass);
}
    // your methods
    // ...
}
```

And when your get your http error code call changeApiBaseUrl().

Hope this helps.

Sorry for my english.